# Arithmetic in a dihedral extension

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\;$L = $\Bbb Q$[$\sqrt[4]{2}$, i ]$\;$ which is a dihedral extension of the rationals.  There are three quadratic and five quartic intermediate fields between L and $\Bbb Q$.  The following questions arose while trying to sort out how certain arithmetic information varies over the different subfields.  Although the third appears somewhat labor intensive, hopefully the first two
are easier.

Questions: $\quad$1)$\,$ Is$\,$  $\Bbb Z$[$\sqrt[4]{2}$, i ] the full ring of integers in L ?  $\;$ 2)  It is easy to see explicitly how the prime$\,$ p = 2$\,$ factors in each of the subfields $\,$$\Bbb Q$[ i ] $\,$and $\Bbb Q$[$\sqrt[4]{2}$]$\,$. $\;$ How does it factor in L , their compositum ?$\quad$3)$\,$ According to Dirichlet's unit theorem$\,$ L $\,$possesses 4 - 1 = 3 fundamental units.  Is it possible to compute them ? (This may be reducible to looking at the units in the quartic subfields.)$\quad$4)$\,$ Finally, are there any references which treat dihedral extensions of $\Bbb Q$ as an extended example or
case study?$\;$  Of special interest would be units, rings of integers, and class numbers.

Thanks

Comment: If you want just short answers, then 1) is no, since $K$ has discriminant $2^{24}$ while $\mathbb Z[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$ has discriminant $2^{30}$ and 2) is: $(2)$ factors as $\mathfrak p^8$ for a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$. I would't know if there are particular tricks for this setting. In principle you can just use standard algorithms to answer these questions, even though this might be really long to do by hand. You can take a look at Cohen's "A course in computational algebraic number theory", which contains this sort of algorithms.

Comment: Thanks, short answers are fine.  The hope was to avoid lengthy hand computations in case any of this information was already available.  Also, question (2) should have been worded more narrowly and was actually aiming at a factorization of the element p = 2 into irreducibles in L .

Comment: Here you go: a generator of $\mathfrak p$ is $7/48a^7 - 1/48a^6 + 29/48a^5 - 5/48a^4 + 7/48a^3 + 11/48a^2 + 185/48a - 5/48$, where $a$ is a root of $x^8 + 4x^6 + 2x^4 + 28x^2 + 1$.